# How to remove an element from a class list

Tags: python, list, class

I have a **class list** like `input= [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]]`.
I want to remove "0" from sublists 0 and 2.
But when I tried `input[1].remove(0)` or `input[2].remove(0)` it removes "0" from all sublists. and the output is like `out = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]`

I wrote this function as well:

```
def remove_ch(self, input, channel_target=0, link_index=[1,2]):
    for i, v in enumerate(input):
        if i == link_index:
            j = input[link_index]
            for ii in j:
                if ii == channel_target:
                    j.pop(ii)
                    break
    input[link_index] = j
```

**How can I get a correct output like the below:**

```
out = [[1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. `x = [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]]; x[0].remove(0)` gives `[[1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]]` as expected.

Comment: @Rasoul - how do you create this *list*?   Maybe that's the root of the problem.  Can you show that *init* part of code from *class definition*?

Comment: your code have a wrong in line "input[link_index] = j"

Comment: @DanielHao I created the list like = a = [[1,2,3]] * 3 then I put in class in the initial part and then call this list by self.channels

Comment: @RasoulSadeghi THAT is the problem. You are storing *the very same list* three times, so when you change it in one place, it gets updated everywhere. You can do `[[1,2,3] for _ in range(3)]` instead to create three independent lists.

Comment: @RasoulSadeghi - you got the answer now.   ^^^ try to redo you creation of list.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have mentioned the wrong indexes in remove() method. The index starts from 0 not from 1. This code is perfectly working for me.

```
input= [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]]
input[0].remove(0)
input[2].remove(0)
```